# Use the Cauchy Integral Formula to evaluate the following integral:

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, solution-verification

> I need to evaluate $$\int_{|z|=0.6}{\frac{e^z}{ze^z-2iz}dz}$$ using the Cauchy Formula

Let $g(z)=\frac{e^z}{ze^z-2iz}$. $g(z)$ has one pole at $z=0$ which lies inside $|z|=0.6$. But $g(z)$ is not analytic on such circle.

I see that I can write $$\frac{e^z}{ze^z-2iz}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{e^z}{e^z-2i}$$

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{e^z-2i}$ which is analytic over $|z|=0.6$. Thus $$\int_{|z|=0.6}{\frac{e^z}{ze^z-2iz}dz}=2\pi i*f(0)=2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2i}{5}\right)$$

Comment: You got the right answer, but I thank that you should explain why is it that you thaink that there are no more poles that matter here.

Comment: Thanks! The poles that comes from $\frac{e^z}{e^z-2i}$ lie outside $|z|=0.6$